# AutoMapper - Multiple Class Libraries

Tags: asp.net, automapper, class-library

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application and a ClassLibrary, both of which define their own `AutoMapper.Profiles` classes.  One example is:

```
public class MyMappings : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MyMappings() : base("MyMappings")
    {
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.User, SessionUser>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.LocationName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LocationForUser.Name));
    }
}
```

In order for BOTH mappings to be configured and in order for one mapping profile to not overwrite the others, is it correct that I should only have ONE AutoMapperConfig (defined in the ASP.NET Forms Application) as follows:?

```
namespace PlatformNET.Mappings
{
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<MyMappings>();
            x.AddProfile<AssessmentClassLib.Mappings.MyMappings>();
        });

    }
}
}
```

and to call it once from Global.asax as follows?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlatformNET.Mappings.AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
}
```

I've currently got a `AutoMapperConfig` class in both Web App and Class Library and am calling both in turn from Global.asax but the 2nd always appears to overwrite the configuration of the first.  I need to know if I am doing this correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiles themselves aren't overriding each other, but each call to `Mapper.Initialize` resets any previous AutoMapper profiles. You should only call `Mapper.Initialize` one time.

The code below demonstrates this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallInitOnce();

        Mapper.Reset();

        CallInitTwice();
    }

    static void CallInitOnce()
    {
        // add profiles one time
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<ClassAToClassBProfile>();
            x.AddProfile<EmptyProfile>();
        });

        var classA = new ClassA()
        {
            MyProperty = 2
        };

        var classB = Mapper.Map<ClassB>(classA);

        Debug.Assert(classA.MyProperty == classB.MyProperty); // profiles work together
    }

    static void CallInitTwice()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<ClassAToClassBProfile>();
        });

        // previous mapping profile is lost
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<EmptyProfile>(); 
        });

        var classA = new ClassA()
        {
            MyProperty = 2
        };
        var classB = Mapper.Map<ClassB>(classA);

        Debug.Assert(classA.MyProperty == classB.MyProperty); // this will fail
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example.  So each ClassLibrary in a solution would typically have one or more Profiles each but only the central Application/Classib (or Test App) has `Mapper.Initialize()` in which you add all the profiles you are going to use.

Comment: Exactly. If you'd like to make it more flexible, you could have each library contain a method like 'GetAllProfiles', then have the central application loop through the results - adding them in its Mapper.Initialize call. That way each library could add new/modify profiles as needed.